# How to display image from Storage(Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try to display images which are uploaded in my storage/app directory.I successfully can upload images in storage but when i try to retrieve it shows a broken image.
To retrieve, my function is :

```
public function getUserImage($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

My view:

```
<img src="{{route('image.show',['filename'=>'123.jpg'])}}"/>
```

When i try to display the image , it shows status 200 (Failed to load response data) but image is not being displayed.Just a broken image is shown.
I have no idea what i am missing .Could you give me any advice ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want? Show the image in a view or return the image with image Content-type ? You are mixing the two options

Comment: @Sangar82 I want to display it in view .Could you guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want send the image to view

In your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // get the filename from somewhere
    $filename = getFilename();

    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);

    return View::make('your_view')
        ->with('file', $file);
}
```

In your view

```
 <img src="/path_where_is_the_file/{{$file}}" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Sangar But it doesnt show anything , doesnt work :(

Comment: It is the way to do it. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem. It is a issue with your $filename. Where are saved the files and what is the content of $filename?

Comment: I´ve updated my answer, you need to add the path where are the images saved

Comment: It retrieves the image from storage but now it shows me the Forbidden error 403.Do i need to do something for storage permission to retrieve file?

Comment: Try this: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/43/changing-storage-path-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Send filename to view and Use src like this

src='/path_to_file/filename.jpg'

Comment: It retrieves the image from Storage but now it shows me the Forbidden error 403.Do i need to do something for storage permission to retrieve file?

Comment: Set permission to 777 of storage folder recursively.